NgZorro Table Angular Not Loading Data Properly
I am trying to load the data which is an array of objects using the ngzorro table
the data I am trying to load is this
{
  "problems": [
    {
      "companies": [
        {
          "color_dark": "#693b73",
          "color_light": "#fdf8a8",
          "logo": null,
          "name": "Apple"
        },
        {
          "color_dark": "#2c6a91",
          "color_light": "#bcb6e2",
          "logo": null,
          "name": "Adobe"
        },
      ],
      "date": "Fri, 12 Apr 2024 00:00:00 GMT",
      "description": "",
      "filename": "codebase/src/Extra_Problems/Searching/FirstBadVersion.java",
      "id": 1,
      "level": "Easy",
      "name": "First Bad Version",
      "notes": "Use Binary Search",
      "remarks": "Kunal Kushwaha",
      "slug": "first-bad-version",
      "status": "Completed",
      "subdirectory": "Searching",
      "type": "Extra Problems",
      "url": "https://leetcode.com/problems/first-bad-version/description/"
    }
  ]
}

This is my component html
<nz-table #filterTable [nzData]="listOfData" nzTableLayout="fixed" [nzPageIndex]="pageIndex" (nzPageIndexChange)="pageChange($event)">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of listOfColumns">
          <th *ngIf="column.allowFilter && column.allowSort"
            [nzWidth]="column.width"
            [nzSortOrder]="column.sortOrder"
            [nzSortFn]="column.sortFn"
            [nzSortDirections]="column.sortDirections"
            [nzFilterMultiple]="column.filterMultiple"
            [nzFilters]="column.listOfFilter"
            [nzFilterFn]="column.filterFn"
          >
            {{ column.name }}
          </th>

          <th *ngIf="!column.allowFilter && column.allowSort"
            [nzWidth]="column.width"
            [nzSortOrder]="column.sortOrder"
            [nzSortFn]="column.sortFn"
            [nzSortDirections]="column.sortDirections"
          >
            {{ column.name }}
          </th>

          <th *ngIf="column.allowFilter && !column.allowSort"
            [nzWidth]="column.width"
            [nzFilterMultiple]="column.filterMultiple"
            [nzFilters]="column.listOfFilter"
            [nzFilterFn]="column.filterFn"
          >
            {{ column.name }}
          </th>

          <th nzCustomFilter *ngIf="column.allowSearch && !column.allowFilter && !column.allowSort">
            {{ column.name }}
            <nz-filter-trigger [(nzVisible)]="visibleMap[column.name.toLowerCase()]" [nzActive]="searchValue.length > 0" [nzDropdownMenu]="menu">
              <span nz-icon nzType="search"></span>
            </nz-filter-trigger>
          </th>

          <th *ngIf="!column.allowFilter && !column.allowSort && !column.allowSearch" [nzWidth]="column.width">
            {{ column.name }}
          </th>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of filterTable.data;let i = index">
        <td><a routerLink="/problem/statement/{{data.slug}}">{{ data.name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ data.type }}<div *ngIf="data.subdirectory">({{data.subdirectory.replaceAll(":", " -> ")}})</div></td>
        <td>{{ data.level }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.status }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <ng-container *ngIf="data.companies && data.companies.length > 0">
            <div style="justify-content: center;">
              <nz-tag *ngFor="let company of data.companies.splice(0, 5)" [nzColor]="getCompanyColor(company)" (click)="tagClick(company.name)">{{company.name}}</nz-tag>
              <ng-container *ngIf="showMore[i]">
                <nz-tag *ngFor="let company of data.companies.splice(5)" [nzColor]="getCompanyColor(company)" (click)="tagClick(company.name)">{{company.name}}</nz-tag>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="data.companies.length > 5">
                <nz-tag *ngIf="!showMore[i]" (click)="showMore[i] = true;" [nzColor]="'transparent'">+ More</nz-tag>
                <nz-tag *ngIf="showMore[i]" (click)="showMore[i] = false;" [nzColor]="'transparent'">- Less</nz-tag>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container *ngIf="!data.companies || data.companies.length == 0">
            <div> No Company Information </div>
          </ng-container>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</nz-table>


My problem is that even if the company data is provided it always shows as "No Company Information" everything is loaded successfully

On inspecting I found companies data does get loaded but it changes

On clicking on the point where the problem lies it highlights this part

EDIT:
Tried using change detection but the issue still exists to debug I have added this line temporarily

the output of following:

After it I changed from data.companies to data.companies.length then:

Here it shows length always zero but when try using regular printing it shows there is something.

EDIT: I was able to solve this the problem was here
<nz-tag *ngFor="let company of data.companies.splice(0, 5)"

I was using splice method it changed the original array changing from splice to slice solved this issue.

Seems, your data changed on init hook before component had completely rendered. There is a simple trick to prevent an error, that might help you.
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
...
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}

To trigger detect changes after view inited.
But I would prefer to figure out how to get data properly with observable/signals to template.

I have tried this already.
It removes the exception but does not solve the issue

I am using resolver to fetch the data from the api
